# Variable unrecognized inside nested for loop in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, variables, for-loop, nested

I am trying to go over two arrays in a bash script, here is the declaration of the variables:s

```
declare -a servers=("server1" "server2")
declare -a services=("service1" "service2")
```

This is the loop I have:

```
for j in "${servers[@]}";do
            'ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@'$j';
            '"for i in "${services[@]}";do echo "$i status in $j"; 
"'/etc/init.d/service-'$i' status'"; done"''
done
```

I am getting the next error when trying to execute it, looks like variable i is empty and it doesn't get any value:

```
for i in service1' 'service2;do echo ' status in 'server1; /etc/init.d/service- status; done'
for i in service1: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
declare -a servers=("server1" "server2")
declare -a services=("service1" "service2")

for server in ${servers[@]}; do
    for service in ${services[@]}; do
        ssh user@$server /etc/init.d/service-$service status
    done
done
```